# Select elements that have data-validate atrribute

Tags: jquery, html

How do i select elements that have my custom data attribute "data-validate" with jQuery
i've tried

```
var matches = $(document).find("[data-validate]");
```

and doesnt work.

Comment: try wrapping up the code in ready handler `$(function(){//your code}):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work fine.  You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kczk3/1/

What exactly isn't working?  I suspect you are having an issue somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to select the element is:

```
$('[data-validate]');
```

and for example to see the text of the element:

```
$('[data-validate]').text();
```